# Constrained eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, constraints

what is the typical way of solving an eigenvalue problem if you have additional constraints??

Let's say for example

$$ \left(\begin{matrix}a && b && c\\ d && e &&f \\ g && h && i \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)$$

with a constraint given by e.g. $$c_2=Ac_1.$$ I feel like I should simply add a first column/row multiplied by $A$ to second column/row ??

All are complex numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $A$?

Comment: Welcome :) (sorry my "Hi" disappeared while editing).  All are complex numbers.

Comment: It would improve the problem statement to clarify which "complex numbers" are knowns and which are unknowns.

Comment: Sorry, $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ are given, we solve for $ c_1,c_2,c_3,\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the $A$ is a constant. For your example above, you should just be able to substitute $c_2=Ac_1$. In which case, you should be able to solve the equation below by your normal methods.

$$ \left(\begin{matrix}a && b && c\\ d && e &&f \\ g && h && i \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ Ac_1 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ Ac_1 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I know I can simply substitute, but now I have too many equations for "$ c_1$". Can I simply add first column/row to second column/row? With this constraint, I should have a problem 2x2, I guess.

Comment: Yes, you're right! If I've rearranged correctly, then you should have something like this.$$ \left(\begin{matrix}a+d+A(b+e)-A && c+f \\ g+Ah && i\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}c_1\\c_3\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}c_1\\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)$$

The important thing is that you've got two unknowns (with the constraint), which makes it a 2x2 system.

Comment: I think similary, but I don't know if is right. After rewriting it as a set of equations and putting the constraint i get something like that:
$$ \left(\begin{matrix}a + Ab && c\\ d +Ae &&f \\ g + Ah && i \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}c_1 \\ Ac_1 \\ c_3\end{matrix}\right)$$

which seems to be overdetermined system of equations.

Comment: I've just realised that my previous comment is incorrect and I'm not sure how to edit it... I think that you're right. So, the equations will only produce solutions for when the first two equations are consistent. 

[See what they've done here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)